# How to use Web Animations API with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web-animations-api

The [Vue3 docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#transition) uses css to efffect transitions, but I wanted to try the (relatively new) [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) instead - partly because I have trouble using variables in CSS.

The following code works:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import comp from './comp.vue'

function moveCircle() {
  let elem = document.getElementById("circle");
  if (elem) {
    elem.animate(
      [
        { transform: "translateX(0px)"},
        { transform: "translateX(320px)"}
      ], 500
    )
  }
}
</script>

<template>
<div>
  <comp id="circle"></comp>
  <button @click="moveCircle()">Move it</button>
</div>
</template>
```

(comp)

```
<script setup></script>

<template>
  <svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </svg>
</template>
```

Vue playground [here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

... but I wanted to get rid of the somewhat cumbersome `getElementById` and instead use [Vue template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs) :

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import comp from './comp.vue'

const circle = ref(null);

function moveCircle() {

  let elem = circle.value;
  if (elem) {
    elem.animate(
      [
        { transform: "translateX(0px)"},
        { transform: "translateX(320px)"}
      ], 500
    )
  }
}
</script>

<template>
<div>
  <comp ref="circle"></comp>
  <button @click="moveCircle()">Move it</button>
</div>
</template>
```

but this does not do the animation ([revised playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)). At one point I had an error `animate() is not a function` but now there is no error - just nothing happens.
What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a ref to a component, `circle.value` gives you the component instance which is evident when you console.log it.  To access the root DOM node of the component, use `circle.value.$el`.  [Documentation reference](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#el)

[Updated Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)